# Error configuración de file-loader, vue 3 y Webpack 5 con font-awesome

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, font-awesome

Estoy desarrollando un app en vue 3 con webpack 5 y php api rest el error el problema es que tengo el siguiente error.

```
dev@PC:/var/www/tools$ npm run dev

> tools@1.0.0 dev
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=webpack.config.js

asset js/main.js 789 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)
asset image/logo.png 6.69 KiB [compared for emit] [from: src/assets/logo.png] (auxiliary name: main)
asset js/locale-en-json.js 571 bytes [compared for emit] (name: locale-en-json)
runtime modules 8.46 KiB 13 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 634 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/axios/ 40.4 KiB 27 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/@vue/ 317 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/@vue/devtools-api/lib/esm/ 939 bytes 10 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/@intlify/ 88.1 KiB 5 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/vue-style-loader/lib/*.js 6.74 KiB
    ./node_modules/vue-style-loader/lib/addStylesClient.js 6.09 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/vue-style-loader/lib/listToStyles.js 671 bytes [built] [code generated]
modules by path ./src/ 19.9 KiB
  javascript modules 19.3 KiB 24 modules
  json modules 555 bytes
    ./src/Locale/es.json 284 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/Locale/en.json 271 bytes [optional] [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ./src/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-1.use[1]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-1.use[3]!./src/sass/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/la-brands-400.eot' in '/var/www/tools/src/sass'
    at finishWithoutResolve (/var/www/tools/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:293:18)
    at /var/www/tools/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:362:15
    at /var/www/tools/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (/var/www/tools/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at /var/www/tools/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (/var/www/tools/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at /var/www/tools/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:87:43
    at /var/www/tools/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:410:5
    at eval (eval at create (/var/www/tools/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /var/www/tools/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:410:5
 @ ./src/sass/app.scss 4:14-217

webpack 5.24.2 compiled with 1 error in 155819 ms
```

Este error me sucede al compilar e intentar mover las fuentes de la-awesome a mi carpeta asset/fonts, se que pude font-awesome pero es lo mismo, ya que la-awesome es font-awesome light
mi archivo de configuración webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const BuildNotifier = require('webpack-build-notifier');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: false,
    entry: [
        './src/app.js', 
        './src/sass/app.scss'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'asset'),
    },
    module:{
        rules:[         
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options:{
                    scss:{
                        user:[
                        'resolve-url-loader',"sass-loader","postcss-loader"]
                    },
                    css:{
                        user:[
                            "vue-style-loader", MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            "css-loader",
                            "postcss-loader"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    "vue-style-loader",  
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: false,
                        },
                    },
                    'resolve-url-loader',
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader",
                        options: {
                            sassOptions:{
                                indentWidth: 4,
                                outputStyle: isDev ? 'expanded' : 'compressed'
                            },
                            sourceMap: false,
                        },
                    },
                    
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /\.module.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)?$/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options:{
                            name: '[folder]/[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/',
                            publicPath:'../fonts/',
                            esModule:false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|webp)?$/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options:{
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'image',
                            publicPath:'../asset/image/',
                            esModule:false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve:{
        extensions: ['.js','.scss', '.css', '.worff', '.woff2', '.ttf', '.eot', '.svg', '.vue'],
        alias:{
            vue: '@vue/runtime-dom'
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: !isDev
    },
    plugins: [
        new Dotenv(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify( isDev === false ),
            __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: false,
            __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: true,
            __VUE_I18N_FULL_INSTALL__: true,
            __VUE_I18N_LEGACY_API__:false,
            __INTLIFY_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        }),
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: isDev ? 'css/[name].css' : 'css/[name].min.css',
            chunkFilename: isDev ? 'css/[id].css' : 'css/[id].[contenthash].css'
        }),         
        new BuildNotifier({
            title: "Sviluppo Compiles",
            logo:""
        })
    ]
};
```

En mi archivo SASS app.scss tengo definida la variable `$la-font-path: "../fonts" !default;` la cual cargo al principio del código osea linea 1 de mi archivo, Espero puedan ayudarme, es primera vez que trabajo con Vue, pero esta configuración de webpack la e usado mucho en otros proyectos y nunca habia tenido este error. además no se como debugear intente poner outputPath como función para colocale un console.log en file-loader pero no tengo resultados.